# Quanteda: error message while tokenizing "unable to find an inherited method for function ‘tokens’ for signature ‘"corpus"’"

Tags: tokenize, text-mining, topic-modeling, text-analysis, quanteda

I have been trying to tokenise and clean my 400 txt documents before using structured topic modelling (STM). I wanted to remove punctuations, stopwords, symbols, etc. However, I get the following error message: 
*"Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function ‘tokens’ for signature ‘"corpus"’"*. This is my original code:

```
answers2 <- tokens(answers_corpus, what = c("word"), remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE,
   remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_separators = TRUE,
   remove_twitter = TRUE, remove_hyphens = TRUE, remove_url = TRUE,
   ngrams = 1L, verbose = quanteda_options("verbose"), include_docvars = TRUE, text_field = "text")
```

I also tried to tokenize a simple string text - just to check if it was an encoding problem while importing my txt files - but I got the same error message, plus a couple of extra ones when I tried to tokenise the the text directly, without converting it to corpus: "*Error: Unable to locate Ciao bella ciao*" and "*Error: No language specified!*". Here is my example code in case someone wants to replicate the error message:

```
prova <- c("Ciao bella ciao")
prova2 <- "Ciao bella ciao"
prova_corpus <- corpus(prova)
prova2_corpus <- corpus(prova2)
prova_tok <- tokens(prova2_corpus)
prova2_tok <- tokens(prova_corpus)
```

The packages that are loaded are: data.table, ggplot2, quanteda, readtext, stm, stringi, stringr, tm, textstem. Any suggestion on how I could proceed to tokenise and clean my texts?

Comment: This is more appropriate as an issue on the [quanteda repository site](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues). Please file it there.

Comment: Thank you. I just did it, here is the link: https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/1408

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts, I managed to find a solution. When several text analysis/topic modelling packages are loaded in Rstudio, the "tokens" functions can overlap. You need to force the command to be quantedas "tokens", ie quanteda::tokens(answers). Here is the updated code

```
answers2 <- quanteda::tokens(answers_corpus, what = c("word"), remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE,
   remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_separators = TRUE,
   remove_twitter = TRUE, remove_hyphens = TRUE, remove_url = TRUE,
   verbose = quanteda_options("verbose"), include_docvars = TRUE, text_field = "text")
```

And the updated example code too:

```
prova <- c("Ciao bella ciao")
prova2 <- "Ciao bella ciao"
prova_corpus <- corpus(prova)
prova2_corpus <- corpus(prova2)
prova_tok <- quanteda::tokens(prova2_corpus)
prova2_tok <- quanteda::tokens(prova_corpus)
```